# Abort | remove delay() function if video is pauzed (do not delay anymore even if delay is not finished)

Tags: jquery, video, delay

I make subtitles system for my video. Right now I am at the stage where subtitle - a box with a text should be shown on spesific second and on spesific position and then after x seconds fade out. However I am stuck at this: if I pauze a video when subtitle is still shown - I want it to remain shown but it runs out of that x seconds and hides anyways.

Question: how can I make subtitle box remain shown regardless of delay function if video is pauzed? and when video plays after being pauzed while subtitle is shown - calculate the remaining seconds (x_total - already_shown =  left_seconds)?

JQUERY:  (two last lines)

```
  $('video').bind('play',function() {
  $('.play_btn').hide();
  if($('.word') && $('.pos') && $('.time') && $('.sec')){ 
     $pos = $('.pos').val().split(','); 
     var seconds = $('.sec').val();
     $('video').on("timeupdate", function(){
       console.log(parseInt(this.currentTime)); 
       if(parseInt(this.currentTime) == $('.time').val()){console.log(seconds);
            $('.video_cover').append("<div class='sub' style='background:white;z-index:2147483647 ;padding:5px;top:"+$pos[0]+"%;left:"+$pos[1]+"%;position:absolute;'>"+$('.word').val()+"</div>");    
       }
         if (this.paused == false) { $('.sub').addClass('sub_spesial_class');$(".sub_spesial_class").delay(seconds*1000).hide(100);console.log('play'); 
            }else{console.log('pauzed');$('.sub').removeClass('sub_spesial_class'); }
    })
}
});
```

As you can see - I have tried adding spesific class when video is playing and adding delay function to that class, then if video is pauzed -  removing that class. And as I though by removing class I would abort that delay function. However that did not work. :(
So, final question: how can I abort/remove/sleep that delay function if video is pauzed? (and then when video plays again - set a new delay function and then hide subtitle)
Thank you in advance for your help, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.sub').stop(true)
```